# Question on isogenies of degree d.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties, group-schemes, isogeny

I am trying to understand the following question (Proposition 5.12. in [ABELIAN VARIETIES](http://van-der-geer.nl/%7Egerard/AV.pdf), Bas Edixhoven, Gerard van der Geer, and Ben Moonen)

- **If $f: X \to Y$ is an isogeny of degree $d$ between abelian varieties then there exists an isogeny
  $g: Y \to X$ with $g \circ f = [d]_X$ and $f ◦ g = [d]_Y$.**

In the proof, I do not understand why we have this factorization when $f$ is annihilated by multiplication by $d$. Further, it seems that this proposition also holds for algebraic groups (Lemma 1.3.4 in [this thesis](http://www.antonellaperucca.net/perucca_thesis.pdf)) which says that

- **Let $A$ and $B$ be smooth, separated, reduced algebraic groups defined over
  a field $K$, $\alpha$ be a $K$-isogeny from $A$ to $B$, and $R$ be in $A(K)$. Let $d$ be the
  exponent of the kernel of $\alpha$ (and hence $d$ divides the degree of $\alpha$). Then there exists $\hat{\alpha}$ in $Hom_K(B, A)$ such that $\hat{\alpha}\circ\alpha= [d]_A$.**

To prove this, the author view algebraic groups as group functors, however I think we can not have the surjectivity of $\alpha_Z:A(Z)\to B(Z)$ for $K-$schemes $Z$ (maybe this is true because of the assumptions of $A$ and $B$) although $\alpha:A\to B$ is surjective (which, as in [Algebraic Groups](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) by J. Milne, means that the underlying map $|A|\to|B|$ is surjective). I really do not know how to get through these, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is isogeny we have isomorphism $$f: X'=X/\ker f\to Y.$$ Let $h: Y\to X'$ be its inverse. Now consider the map $[d]: X\to X$ multiplication by $d$, which factors through $[d]: X'\to X$, since $d$ kills $\ker f$. Now define $$g: Y\to X$$ as
$$g: Y\xrightarrow{h} X'\xrightarrow{[d]} X.$$
Now simply observe that $g\circ f=[d]$.

Similarly, $f\circ g=[d].$

Comment: I got your point, thanks!